Why is table column width changing here?
I am new to tailwind and css and I would like to understand exactly why the first table column is resized on hover here:


<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="flex">
        <table class="grow">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>col1</th>
                    <th>col2</th>
                    <th>col3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="flex flex-row">
                            <div
                                class="ml-1 px-2 py-1 hover:font-semibold hover:border-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white">
                                Some Text</div>
                            row1-1
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td>row1-2</td>
                    <td>row1-3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>



I know it has something to do with the font size increase and addition of a border but I do not exactly understand why it is happening and how to address it properly. Any help is appreciated!
I already tried multiple different classes but I cannot make it work without fixing the actual column size, which I do not want to do because it should be at least a bit responsive.

It's not resizing on hover in your example.

You've got class="grow" on the table which is causing the column to change size on hover.
The grow class applies flex-grow: 1 which makes the table fill the available horizontal space within its flex container.
The styles you're applying likely change the size of the contents inside the cell which affects the overall size of the column as a result of the flex-grow: 1 applied to the table.
As a remedy you could have the table fill available space by default:


<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="flex justify-center">
  <!-- Added justify-center to center the table -->
  <table class="w-full">
    <!-- Removed the grow class and added w-full to make the table fill the available space -->
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>col1</th>
        <th>col2</th>
        <th>col3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="flex flex-row">
            <div class="ml-1 px-2 py-1 hover:font-semibold hover:border-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-500 hover:text-white">
              Some Text
            </div>
            row1-1
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>row1-2</td>
        <td>row1-3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>




thanks for the answer, unfortunately it does not fix it. I generate tailwind using the cli, but I do not have any custom css in there... The table is max width all the time, but the distribution of the column widths changes with the content inside the cell...

As far as I know, that's normal behavior for a table anyway even in baseline HTML. Something to consider.
